# bash: ignoring specific fields during file comparisons

Tags: bash

I have 2 files with following text:

OldFile:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root
                       18G  2.4G   15G  14% /
tmpfs                 590M  276K  590M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   31M  429M   7% /boot
```

NewFile

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root
                       18G  2.7G   15G  14% /
tmpfs                 590M  264K  590M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   31M  429M   7% /boot
/dev/sdb1             3.8G  1.1G  2.8G  28% /media/9C6F-1ECD
```

Now in output file I just want following line. as this is newly added.

```
/dev/sdb1             3.8G  1.1G  2.8G  28% /media/9C6F-1ECD
```

but instead I'm getting following output as one number is also changed from 2.4 to 2.7.

```
                        18G  2.7G   15G  14% /
/dev/sdb1             3.8G  1.1G  2.8G  28% /media/9C6F-1ECD
```

so this is creating problem for me. I just want completely newly added line.

Comment: Define "only a few words". I guess one can write a program that will print lines of the second file that are not present in the first file, but as you put it the problem is too broad.

Comment: what do you mean completely changed? Perhaps at least n words modified?Or character difference of n or more?

Comment: I am not at a linux box - but maybe you could try to use the `diff` command and operate on the output to filter only completely changed lines.

Comment: You certainly can't do that with grep options `-F` and `-x`.

Comment: Well -- now that you give us your *real* problem, it's easy -- you can use uniq's support for skipping specific fields. Trying to hide what you're actually doing from folks who want to help you is a road to pain and suffering.

Comment: actually whenever i put something like this...everyone starts saying "use UDEV,libusb... that is better" and I dont want to use those things but also can't explain them everytime...thats why I was hiding :)... hope u dont mind

Comment: I mind. You wasted not only my time, but that of everyone else who had to guess what you were trying to do, and spend their effort crafting unhelpful answers as a result. That said, the question is now edited to represent your real problem, and I hope that the answer provided is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put the parts you *do* want to compare onto the end, as so:

```
df -P | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1 ":" $6 "\t" $0 }' | sort >comm-test.1
df -P | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1 ":" $6 "\t" $0 }' | sort >comm-test.2
```

Then:

```
join -t $'\t' -j 1 -o 2.2 \
  <(comm -13 \
     <(cut -f1 comm-test.1) \
     <(cut -f1 comm-test.2)) \
  comm-test.2
```

Note the use of `df -P` to ensure that the output from df is not split onto multiple lines (as in your example).

By the way -- obscuring your problem was supremely unhelpful. Please do not do this in the future.

Comment: Thanks. thats working but I think you mistakenly put .new at the end... coz files created by df-p doesn't contain ".new". please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @user115079 You're right -- that was an artifact from my own testing.

Answer (score 0):

This may get you close to what you want,

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines oldfile newfile
```

The main problem is that it also includes the small changes that you want to exclude.  If it's safe to assume that lines with small changes will not include '|' surrounded by whitespace, then we can delete the corresponding diff output to leave only those lines that are added or removed.

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines oldfile newfile | sed '/[ TAB][ TAB]*|[ TAB][ TAB]*/ d'
```

where "TAB" should be the tab character.

This will show lines added and removed with an **important limitation:** If a line addition and deletion are adjacent, diff will report a changed line (with the '|') and this output will be discarded by the sed filter.

If you need the added/removed lines to appear as they do in the files, you can remove the < and > from the diff output using additional sed commands.  For example, to get rid of the > indicating a line addition:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines oldfile newfile | sed -e '/[ TAB][ TAB]*|[ TAB][ TAB]*/ d' -e 's/^[ TAB][ TAB]*>[ TAB][ TAB]*\(.*$\)/\1/'
```

But note that this will also remove any leading whitespace from the line.

Comment: above solution is much better apart from one thing that it shows me output like this "    > ddddd". as you mentioned that it should remove > but it is not doing it. can you fix it and make it to remove white spaces and then ">". rest if working fine so far.

Comment: can i use "cut" to remove these spaces and ">".

Comment: yes. I just copy and paste last syntax given by you. it works fine apart form putting spaces and > infront of line. previously i was using diff with grep and cut to end > and it was working fine. I have no issue. just want it right. with this command "diff -y --suppress-common-lines System_Detail NewDetail | sed -e '/[ TAB]*|[ TAB]*/ d' | sed -e 's/^[ TAB]*>[ TAB]*\(.*$\)/\1/'" I'm getting" whitespace and then > /dev/sdb1             3.8G  1.1G  2.8G  28% /media/9C6F-1ECD" 
"

Comment: Please clarify "Actual Tabs"? I think I'm not getting your point. I'm running this command on shell prompt (not in script) and when i press TAB (after removing TAB word), nothing happens ( no spaces are put there)... can you please clarify. Th

Comment: @user115079, The reason nothing happens with you hit tab key is because the shell is trying to do tab expansion and there are no matches.  To insert a tab character from the command line, quickly press esc key followed by tab key.  If this doesn't work for your setup, put the command in a bash script, so that you can use vi/emacs to insert the tab characters.

Comment: I've tried it in script and pressed tab button. it puts tab there but result is same.. "spaces and >" ... let me try escape button now.

Comment: @user115079, make sure you put both tab and a space between each pair of brackets

Answer (score 0):

Finds only lines that have no similarities

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines /yourfile1 /yourfile2 | grep "<" | sed 's/  .*//g'
```

Comment: To catch added lines, you probably need to grep ">" as well.

Comment: diff -y --suppress-common-lines /yourfile1 /yourfile2 | awk '/</;/>/' | sed 's/  .*//g'

Comment: Prompted by Nick Atoms I added the awk command for both '<' and '>'